# Reduce video file size in Flutter / Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working on an application where users can upload videos to our server. They can select videos from their gallery, so I would like to reduce them before uploading.

I would like to know if there is any way to reduce the video file size with Flutter/ Dart. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: since my original answer, there's another package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_compress with friendlier API

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_ffmpeg is pretty good, and has well-documented instruction

```dart
import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/flutter_ffmpeg.dart';

 final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();

 _flutterFFmpeg.execute("-i file1.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 file2.mp4").then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc"));
```

Check the `rc` code, and if it's successful, open `file2.mp4`, which is the compressed/processed file.

Comment: Just be aware that `flutter_video_compress` don't support null-safety!

Answer (score 3):

I am using [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) plugin
detailed:

```
static Future<String> ReduceSizeAndType(videoPath, outDirPath) async {
    assert(File(videoPath).existsSync());

    final arguments = '-y -i $videoPath ' +
        '-preset ultrafast -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 ' +
        '-c:v libx264 -b:v 720k ' +
        '-c:a copy ' +
        '"$outDirPath/file2.mp4"';

    final int rc = await _encoder.execute(arguments);
    assert(rc == 0);

    return outDirPath;
  }
```

You can change the quality and size of your video with increasing and decreasing 720k quantity.
Returned of "$outDirPath" is your output video path.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[flutter_video_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_compress)** package

**Installing**:

add `flutter_video_compress` as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.

#### Usage :

**Create an instance**

```
final _flutterVideoCompress = FlutterVideoCompress();
```

**Get thumbnail from video path**

```
final uint8list = await _flutterVideoCompress.getThumbnail(
  file.path,
  quality: 50, // default(100)
  position: -1 // default(-1)
);
```

**Get thumbnail file from video path**

```
final thumbnailFile = await _flutterVideoCompress.getThumbnailWithFile(
  file.path,
  quality: 50, // default(100)
  position: -1 // default(-1)
);
```

**Convert video to a gif**

```
final file = await _flutterVideoCompress.convertVideoToGif(
  videoFile.path,
  startTime: 0, // default(0)
  duration: 5, // default(-1)
  // endTime: -1 // default(-1)
);
print(file.path);
```

**Compression Video**

```
final info = await _flutterVideoCompress.compressVideo(
  file.path,
  quality: VideoQuality.DefaultQuality, // default(VideoQuality.DefaultQuality)
  deleteOrigin: false, // default(false)
);
print(info.toJson().toString());
```

You can learn more about this package **[here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_compress)**

Comment: It doesn't support null safety and some other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) package:

**pubspec.yaml**

```
ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl: ^5.1.0
```

**ffmpeg_service.dart**

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as io;

import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/ffmpeg_kit.dart';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/return_code.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

enum FfmpegCompressScale {
  none(null),
  half(4),
  oneThird(6),
  oneQuarter(8),
  oneFifth(10);

  const FfmpegCompressScale(this.value);

  final int? value;
}

enum FfmpegPreset {
  ultrafast,
  superfast,
  veryfast,
  faster,
  fast,
  medium,
  slow,
  slower,
  veryslow,
}

class FfmpegService {
  const FfmpegService();

  Future<io.Directory> get _tempVideoDir async {
    final temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    return await io.Directory(p.join(temp.path, 'video')).create();
  }

  Future<String?> compressVideo(
    String path, {
    FfmpegPreset preset = FfmpegPreset.medium,
    FfmpegCompressScale scale = FfmpegCompressScale.none,
    int crf = 28,
  }) async {
    try {
      final name = p.basenameWithoutExtension(path);
      final epoch = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      final outputPath = [(await _tempVideoDir).path, '${name}_$epoch.mp4']
          .join(io.Platform.pathSeparator);
      final command = [
        '-y -i $path -preset ${preset.name}',
        if (scale.value != null)
          '-vf scale="trunc(iw/${scale.value})*2:trunc(ih/${scale.value})*2"',
        '-c:v libx264 -crf $crf',
        '-c:a copy $outputPath',
      ].join(' ');
      final completer = Completer<String?>();
      await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(
        command,
        (session) async {
          final code = await session.getReturnCode();
          if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(code)) {
            return completer.complete(outputPath);
          } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(code)) {
            return completer.complete(null);
          }
          final state = await session.getState();
          return completer.completeError(Exception(
            'FFmpeg process exited with state ${state.name} '
            'and return code $code.',
          ));
        },
        (log) => debugPrint(log.getMessage()),
      );
      return await completer.future;
    } catch (e, s) {
      debugPrint('Failed to compress video $e $s');
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```dart
final path = await const FfmpegService().compressVideo(
  file.path,
  preset: FfmpegPreset.veryfast,
  scale: FfmpegCompressScale.half,
);
```

You can work with the [constant rate factor](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) and [scaling](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling) of the video depending on your preferences. You also need to remember that the lower the processing speed, the more the file is compressed.

I use the [H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) codec for more device compatibility, if you want you can use [H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for more compression.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@holofox's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76769056/4949756) answer
You will need to add the [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) in your `Pubspec` file like this

```
ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl: ^6.0.3
```

Also, you may need to add this code in the android/app/build.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so'
    }
```

and change the `minSdkVersion` to 24

and this is an updated code adding the progress callback to the compress function

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as io;

import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/ffmpeg_kit.dart';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/return_code.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_video_info/flutter_video_info.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

enum FfmpegCompressScale {
  none(null),
  half(4),
  oneThird(6),
  oneQuarter(8),
  oneFifth(10);

  const FfmpegCompressScale(this.value);

  final int? value;
}

enum FfmpegPreset {
  ultrafast,
  superfast,
  veryFast,
  faster,
  fast,
  medium,
  slow,
  slower,
  verySlow,
}

class FfmpegService {
  const FfmpegService();

  Future<io.Directory> get _tempVideoDir async {
    final temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    return await io.Directory(p.join(temp.path, 'video')).create();
  }

  Future<String?> compressVideo(
    String path, {
    FfmpegPreset preset = FfmpegPreset.veryFast,
    FfmpegCompressScale scale = FfmpegCompressScale.none,
    int crf = 28,
    void Function(int)? progressCallback,
  }) async {
    try {
      final name = p.basenameWithoutExtension(path);
      final epoch = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      final flutterVideoInfo = FlutterVideoInfo();
      final videoInfo = await flutterVideoInfo.getVideoInfo(path);

      final outputPath = [(await _tempVideoDir).path, '${name}_$epoch.mp4']
          .join(io.Platform.pathSeparator);
      final command = [
        '-y -i $path -preset ${preset.name}',
        if (scale.value != null)
          '-vf scale="trunc(iw/${scale.value})*2:trunc(ih/${scale.value})*2"',
        '-c:v libx264 -crf $crf',
        '-c:a copy $outputPath',
      ].join(' ');
      final completer = Completer<String?>();
      await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(
          command,
          (session) async {
            final code = await session.getReturnCode();
            if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(code)) {
              return completer.complete(outputPath);
            } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(code)) {
              return completer.complete(null);
            }
            final state = await session.getState();
            return completer.completeError(Exception(
              'FFmpeg process exited with state ${state.name} '
              'and return code $code.',
            ));
          },
          (log) => debugPrint(log.getMessage()),
          (statistics) {
            if (progressCallback == null) return;
            final time = statistics.getTime();
            if (time > 0 && videoInfo?.duration != null) {
              final progress = (time / videoInfo!.duration! * 100).toInt();
              progressCallback(progress);
            }
          });
      return await completer.future;
    } catch (e, s) {
      debugPrint('Failed to compress video $e $s');
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

don't forget to add [flutter_video_info](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_info) `flutter_video_info: ^1.3.1` to your `Pubspec` file to use this updated code

Finally, Thanks @holofox for your great answer.

Answer (score 0):

@eslam

When adding `ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl: ^6.0.3` and `packagingOptions { pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so' }` it is giving an error about Duplicated classes such as  `com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.StreamInformation found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-https-6.0-2-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-https:6.0-2) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-6.0-2-runtime`. what other configurations are missing? @es

Answer (score -3):

You can try to search in https://pub.dartlang.org if exist any package that have that function or similar .