# How to compress a video in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

How to compress a video in flutter?
I'm using image_picker to pick video from gallery which compress the video from 30MB to 10MB on iOS but in android there is no compression. 
Is there a way to manipulate the size or quality of video using dart? 
Are there any existing packages in flutter to compress video?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: since my original answer (as pointed out in the comment), there's another package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_compress with friendlier API

See my answer in another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52072060/reduce-video-file-size-in-flutter-dart):

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_ffmpeg is pretty good, and has well-documented instruction

```dart
import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/flutter_ffmpeg.dart';

 final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();

 _flutterFFmpeg.execute("-i file1.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 file2.mp4").then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc"));
```

Check the `rc` code, and if it's successful, open `file2.mp4`, which is the compressed/processed file.

Comment: It's a nasty unclear library though. ```flutter_video_compress``` is much nicer to setup and use.

Comment: @OliverDixon on the other hand,     flutter_video_compress seems abandoned.

Comment: How can i set the output directory in flutter_video_compress?

Comment: flutter_video_compress isn't that good.. if i even set it to medium level, i see blurred video... on the other hand ffmpeg crf attribute compresses videos without compromizing the video quality. I am not sure how to use it in flutter.

Answer (score 5):

Use **[video_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress)** package

**How to use** :

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  video_compress: ^2.1.0
```

And import it :

```
import 'package:video_compress/video_compress.dart';
```

**Video compression**

```
MediaInfo mediaInfo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
  path,
  quality: VideoQuality.DefaultQuality, 
  deleteOrigin: false, // It's false by default
);
```

You can learn more about this package **[here](https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress)**.