# How to compress and upload video to firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want to compress the video before uploading the video to firebase.

```
final file =  await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
//compress and then move to the code below
        StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("video").child(id);
        StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file, StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'));
        var storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
        var downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        final String url = downloadUrl.toString();
        fb.child(id).set({
          "id": id,
          "link": url,
        }).then((value) {
          print("Done");
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
```

Comment: I found an answer for this question on another similar question, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66091797/11617924

Comment: You're trying to upload the file to Cloud Storage, not to Cloud Firestore. But  I wonder how this is any different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290269/how-to-compress-a-video-in-flutter

Comment: I dont understand the dart package. Should I use the executed line(info.path) here.StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(info.path)StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `video_compress` package:

https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress

```
MediaInfo mediaInfo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
  file.path,
  quality: VideoQuality.DefaultQuality, 
  deleteOrigin: false, // It's false by default
);
```

Comment: I dont understand the dart package. Should I use the executed line(info.path) here.StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(info.path)StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'));

Comment: You just use `file.path`(I will edit my answer to be more clear)

Comment: I got an error stating mediaInfo can't be assigned to parameter type 'File'